# Creating Prototypes in a stepscope in Spring Batch so that parameters can be injected

Tags: spring, spring-batch

**Problem**

I would like to create a single prototype for different readers in the batch job, however I also want to inject parameters into each of the readers. The prototype requires the annotation '@Scope("prototype")' and the parameter injection requires '@Scope("step")'. Is there a way to create a prototype where I can also inject my parameters?

**Background**

I have a batch job responible for handling different types of input. Each of the different input types requires a separate reader with only very subtle differences. Depending on the type of the input a reader is selected using a JobExecutionDecider.

**Workaround**

I currently just define each of the different readers in a separate bean methods with the step scope annotation on each of them.

**Goal**

```
  @Autowired
  private JobExecutionDecider namespaceDecider;
  @Autowired
  protected StepBuilderFactory steps;
  
  @Bean
  protected Flow itemFlow() {
    FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> flow = new FlowBuilder<>("itemFlow");
    flow.start(namespaceDecider);
    flow.from(namespaceDecider).on(V1).to(itemStep(itemReader(Type1.class, null)));
    flow.from(namespaceDecider).on(V2).to(itemStep(itemReader(Type2.class, null)));
    flow.from(namespaceDecider).on(V3).to(itemStep(itemReader(Type3.class, null)));
    return flow.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  protected <T extends ItemType> Step itemStep(ItemReader<? extends T> itemReader) {
    return steps.get("itemStep").<ItemType, Order> chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)//
        .reader(itemReader).processor(itemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter()).build();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  protected <T> ItemReader<T> itemReader(Class<T> claz, @Value("to-be-injected") ItemMessage itemMessage) {
    return xmlObjectReader(claz, itemMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A step-scoped bean will be instantiated for every step requesting it, meaning each step will have its own instance. So you can think of it as a prototype bean, and there is no need to declare it as a prototype.

Comment: Yes you can think of it as a prototype in a sence that every step has it's own (single) instance. However, in my problem I want to have multiple instances per step. This is something I can do with prototypes, but am not able to do with step scopes.

Comment: `in my problem I want to have multiple instances per step`: A step can have a single reader/writer. Why are you looking to have multiple instance per step? The step-scope allows you to make each step have its own instance of the reader/writer, in the case for example of a worker step in a partitioned setup: each worker step will have its own reader configured to read data of a given partition, but I see no point of having multiples instances of the reader/writer for a single step.

Comment: You're right I want a single reader per step but I want multiple steps with the readers as prototypes. I added a code sample that hopefully clarifies my goal.